# How to abbreviate Chrome, Safari and Opera?

Tags: browser, acronym, abbreviation

How do I abbreviate Google Chrome, Apple Safari and Opera? I know that (MS)IE goes for (Microsoft) Internet Explorer and Fx is for Firefox. What about the rest?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, Apple Safari and Opera = Browser; Internet Explorer = IE

Comment: @Tower, Isn't firefox FF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome, Apple Safari and Opera does not have official abbreviations but i have seen google chrome as GC, Cr and Crm.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on context. If the audience knows that you speak about browsers, use something short enough, e.g. FF, GCr, Sf, O, IE. Were you able to decipher these? They will be, too.

Of course, if the audience is not well acquainted with various browsers, you need to use full names.

In either case, use icons and brand colors, if possible. A red O is definitely Opera, and a big blue "e" is what most people associate with the word 'browser'.